# Rails 5.1.4 validates fields in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.1.4, I want to validates two fields (:content , : image)  in my model Post. How can I validate by saying that one of those fields must be set or both? . Display an error message when both is blank. If need to post any code, just let me know.  Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate it in your `post.rb` file with a `before_save` action like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord 

  validate :content_or_image

  def content_or_image
    if content.blank? and image.blank?
      errors.add(:content, :image, message: "You need a content or image to create this post")
    end
  end 

end
```

Comment: Hi Pablo,  i tried with your solution,  but it doesn't work for me,  the post is being done with empty values for both

Comment: Hi Jalloh ! It was supposed to be a `validate` instead of a `before_action`. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you very much Pablo it works by know. have a nice day. You're the best.

Comment: Great to know! Have a nice one as well.